# Template operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates

So I am writting a code where I am sorting something. And I have my definition in a class term.cpp

```
friend bool operator<(Term T1, Term T2);
```

Then in a Template I was provided with we have a implementation of the merge sorting algorithm as

```
void SortingList<T>::merge_sort(int (*compare)(T T1, T T2));
```

Now suppose I have the following

```
SortingList<Term> randomList;
randomList.merge_sort(???);
```

So my question is what do I put in the ??? I tried

```
randomList.merge_sort(Term::operator<(Term T1, Term T2));
```

but it did not work and i'm confused, I do not know how the compiler wants the operator put inside the merge_sort implementation

Comment: Why does `int (*compare)(T T1, T T2)` return `int`?

Comment: i'm working off someone elses template so I have no clue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create a `compare` wrapper if the requirement is to return an `int`. This would convert the `bool` returned from `operator<`

```
int compareTerm(Term T1, Term T2)
{
   if (T1 < T2)
      return -1;
   else if (T2 < T1)
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
}
```

Then just pass `compareTerm` to `merge_sort`.

Comment: I see and I actually wrote a function called compareTerm ...  that makes since

Comment: What if i wanted to pass in a value to comparTerm like comparTerm(Term,Term,int) then how would I call merge_sort?

Comment: Then you could use a [`functor object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses) instead of a function, and pass extra parameters to its constructor.